# Issues with output ” character using puts() function in C

Tags: c

I have tried `puts("”");`, `puts("\”");` but every time I get `ö` as output so escape character doesn't works. Do I have wrong code page? If it is possible I don't want to use `printf("%c",smth);`

Comment: That's not the normal ASCII double-quote `"`, but some kind of Unicode character. Perhaps your console or terminal environment doesn't have the same encoding as the one you use for that quote? What is the encoding of that character? What encoding is the source-file saved as? What encoding is the terminal set up to use?

Comment: DId you actually get the intended output with `printf("%c",smth)`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky didnt even try it, im actually new in C and on research I found people using that for some operations with characters but thats not what I want.

Comment: @DScounterGO OK, it will probably be no different. If you're new, you should forget about using these special characters for the moment.

Comment: Always check what you copy from a web-page, etc.. as it may not be ASCII. C is written in ASCII, e.g. [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) and any use of other characters requires special handling. In you case it seems almost certain that the `"` you thought you copied was actual a html `&ldquo` or `&rdquo`. It is actually the `e2 80 9d` character, e.g. confirmed with `echo 'puts("”");' | hexdump -Cv` (the `&rdquo`)

Comment: @Jabberwocky thats true but that was my homework. I dont even know why I learn C, one lesson per week sounds useless and we were in C++ for a longer time. I also have C# to learn for Unity scripts but thats my choice. whole C family huh

Comment: Never copy any code from place that doesn't show code in a distinct monospace font.

Comment: @DScounterGO what __exactly__ was your homework? I doubt that they would want beginners to mess around with UNICODE and/or UTF-8. Are you sure you don't simply want `puts("\"")` instead of `puts("\”")`? Look closely at `”` vs `"`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Not exactly, I had to output whole string where one of characters was `”` for sure. Stupid imo, maybe thats mistake in exercise.

Comment: @DScounterGO it's probably a typo in the exercise. Modern word processors often substitute `"` with `”` during typing.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Maybe, anyway thanks for help. Ill just skip that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression is the 2nd one with a regular double quote:

```
puts("\"");
```

If you want to use the UTF-8 character then it's a terminal font / encoding issue and not a C question:

```
$ echo '"”"' | od -c
0000000   " 342 200 235   "  \n
0000006
```